# Mouse click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I **make a new mouse click**  in `jquery` ?

```
<div id="myId> Mouse Click  programatically</div>
```

I have a mouser listener ,

```
$("#myId").mousedown(function(){

        alert("Mouse clicked programatically")l

});
```

**My need :**

I need to do the `Mouse click programatically in jquery ?`

Comment: And what's wrong with `$('#myId').click();` ?

Comment: $('#myId').click() only subscribes on click event

Comment: what do you want exactly?

Comment: @KitePlayer check my answer. this will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems to me is this:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $("#myId").on('click mousedown', function () {
       alert("Mouse clicked programatically");
    }).click();
});
```

[**Checkout this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/grCb3/1)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to do the Mouse click programatically in jquery ?

Comment: "`Mouse click programatically in jquery`" not well clear. If you could explain your issue bit more clearly.

Comment: I need to listen the `mouseDown` event.But I don't want to use the mouse .I need to do the mouse click programatically when my DOM is fully loaded.

Comment: See the updated answer and fiddle.

Answer (score -1):

Just call `$('#myId').mousedown();`

or you could change your code to:

```
$("#myId").click(function(){

        alert("Mouse clicked programatically")l

});
```

and call `$('#myId').click();`